# How to write Advanced Policies for IHP DataSync?

Tags: ihp

I have the following schema:

```
Users: id, name

Group: id, room_id

Rooms: id

ChatMessages: id, body, user_id, room_id, created_at
```

The [Guide](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/realtime-spas.html#defining-a-security-policy) shows how to create a basic policy for `user_id` column with `ihp_user_info()` function. However, here I want to create a policy for ChatMessages such that, for each group, I can access all chat_messages and along with the user names.